# How to change Google assistant associated account?

Tags: google-account, google-assistant

If I have multiple Google account signed in. How do I change the associated account which Google assistant will use?

So Google assistant will load the personalized settings from the correct account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Google Assistant by holding Home button.

Go to **Explorer** (Tap the Explorer icon on Top-Right Side).

[image: Tap the Explorer icon on Top-Right Side]

Tap the Menu icon and choose **Account**, Then select your account. 
[image: Tap the Menu icon and choose Account]

**Done.**